# Terraform and AWS Assume Role

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Given existence of `default` in `~/.aws/credentials`

```yaml
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AFAKEYHFVDLCHVNOISYGV
aws_secret_access_key=RApidgudsphAFaK+e97dslvxchnv
```

and a *named profile* called **backendRole** in `~/.aws/config`

```yaml
[profile backendRole]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::123456789101:role/backend
source_profile=default
```

using aws cli, I confirm that `default` can assume backendRole and has permissions to an s3 bucket and dynamodb table by running:

```
aws s3 ls s3://random-tf-state-bucket --profile backendRole

aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name random-tf-state-lock-table --profile backendRole --region us-east-2
```

The above commands do not return (AccessDenied) thus conforming access

**Expectation**:

According to terraform [documentation/blog](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041289933-Using-AWS-AssumeRole-with-the-AWS-Terraform-Provider) and given a main.tf file set up like the below:

```
    terraform {
      required_version = "1.0.4"
      required_providers {
        aws = {
          source  = "hashicorp/aws"
          version = "3.53.0"
        }
      }
    }

    terraform {
      backend "s3" {
      }
    }

    provider "aws" {
      region                  = "us-eat-1"
      profile                 = "default"
      shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"

      assume_role {
        role_arn    ="arn:aws:iam::123456789101:role/backend"
      }

    }
```

and `s3.backend.tfvars` file:

```
bucket         = "random-tf-state-bucket"
key            = "terraform.tfstate"
region         = "us-east-2"
dynamodb_table = "random-tf-state-lock-table"
encrypt        = true
```

running `terraform init -backend-config=s3.backend.tfvars`  should work.

**Result:**

```
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.
│
│ Please see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│   For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

**Question**:

What step in this process am I missing?

Comment: If you need to initialize first to authenticate for the backend, then you can`terraform init -backend=false` and then `terraform init`. Does that fix your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issue reported [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26995) was helpful in getting a solution.

**Solution:**

The key to resolving my error was realizing that Terraform allows you to use different profiles for configuring your S3 backend and CRUDing resources.

As this was the case in my Org, *s3.backend.tfvars* should have looked like:

```bash
bucket         = "random-tf-state-bucket"
key            = "terraform.tfstate"
region         = "us-east-2"
dynamodb_table = "random-tf-state-lock-table"
encrypt        = true
profile        = "s3BackendAccountReadWriteProfile"
```

While the *provider block* should have looked like:

```
provider "aws" {
  region                    = var.aws_region
  shared_credentials_file   = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile                   = "envDependentCrudProfile"
  
}
```

So basically, I had to tell Terraform what profile to use when configuring our S3 backend (see updated `s3.backend.tfvars`) and also tell Terraform what profile to use when creating resources (see updated aws `provider` block).